# Collation for accent-insensitive comparison on Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, collation, localization, international-components-unicode

On PG 13 documentation, there are several examples of ICU collations for specialized purposes.  It is also mentioned that ICU locales exist that allow creating collations to ignore accents, and that they can be found on https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/master/common/bcp47/collation.xml

However, after reading that document, I am still unclear on what is the locale I should use to create an ICU collation for accent insensitive comparisons in Spanish.

What is the name of such an ICU locale?  Is there any list of ICU Spanish collations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a case sensitice, but accent insensitive locale for Spain that works with recent versions of ICU:

```
CREATE COLLATION spanish_noaccent (
   PROVIDER = 'icu',
   LOCALE = 'es-ES-u-ks-level1-kc',
   DETERMINISTIC = FALSE
);

SELECT 'Olé' = 'Ole' COLLATE spanish_noaccent;

 ?column? 
══════════
 t
(1 row)

SELECT 'Olé' = 'ole' COLLATE spanish_noaccent;

 ?column? 
══════════
 f
(1 row)
```

`ks-level1` means "case and accent insensitive", and `kc` adds case sensitivity.

See [my blog post](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/icu-collations-against-glibc-2-28-data-corruption/) for more.

Comment: That blog post should be referenced from the docs.  That would save people a lot of time.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I could not find in your blog post the definitions of variant subtags `kf` and `kr`, which are used in the examples of the docs.  Do you know their meaning?

Comment: You can look that up in https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-13.html